# How can I run my performance tests more than ten times?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, performance-testing, xctest

By default Xcodes performance tests are run ten times and my result is the average of those ten tests. The problem is the averaged result varies considerably each time I run it so I have to run the test at least five times to get a converged result. This is both tedious and time consuming; is there a way to configure either XCode or the unit test itself to run more than ten times?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the latest Xcode (11.0+) you don't need swizzling to change iterations count. Use the following [function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/3194266-measure):

`func measure(options: XCTMeasureOptions, block: () -> Void)`

This will allow you to specify [`XCTMeasureOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctmeasureoptions) which has `iterationCount` property.

Interesting note from docs:

> **A performance test runs its block `iterationCount+1` times**, ignoring the first iteration and recording metrics for the remaining iterations. The test ignores the first iteration to reduce measurement variance associated with “warming up” caches and other first-run behavior.

Answer (score 8):

a class dump of XCTestCase exposes this method:

```
- (void)_recordValues:(id)arg1 forPerformanceMetricID:(id)arg2 name:(id)arg3 unitsOfMeasurement:(id)arg4 baselineName:(id)arg5 baselineAverage:(id)arg6 maxPercentRegression:(id)arg7 maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation:(id)arg8 maxRegression:(id)arg9 maxStandardDeviation:(id)arg10 file:(id)arg11 line:(unsigned long long)arg12;
```

when this method is swizzled the first parameter (arg1) has the 10 durations:

```
["0.003544568",
"0.003456569",
"0.003198263",
"0.003257955",
"0.003508724",
"0.003454298",
"0.003461192",
"0.00423787",
"0.003359195",
"0.003335757"]
```

i added 4 new values (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0) to the end of this list before passing it back to the original implementation, but unfortunately a different class that observes, `XCTestLog`, has an internal sanity check that gets tripped:

```
Assertion failure in +[XCTestLog _messageForTest:didMeasureValues:forPerformanceMetricID:name:unitsOfMeasurement:baselineName:baselineAverage:maxPercentRegression:maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation:maxRegression:maxStandardDeviation:file:line:]
caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "Performance Metrics must provide 10 measurements."
```

once the `XCTestLog` method is also overridden so it doesn't assert, the additional 4 values can be added without any complaints. unfortunately the view still only shows the 10 results.

it does however update the total time + standard deviation values in the mini view.

**Before Swizzling**

[image: Before Swizzle]

**After Swizzling and adding 4 values**
[image: After Swizzle]

in order to view more than 10 results one would probably have to tweak the XCode runtime to tell the table to show more items.

Comment: Does this work accurately? The increase from 0.003 seconds to 0.717 seconds seems a bit much for three new entries.

Comment: yes this works accurately. the mean for the original 10 values was 0.00348, and the mean of the 14 (after adding 1, 2, 3, 4) values was 0.71677

Comment: (0.003544568 + 0.003456569 + 0.003198263 + 0.003257955 + 0.003508724 + 0.003454298 + 0.003461192 + 0.00423787 + 0.003359195 + 0.003335757 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4)/14

Comment: I would strongly not recommend this approach.  As soon as apple changes any of the classes in the XCTest framework, any of this could break.

Comment: This method no longer works in XCTestCase as of Xcode 13. Have you found it somewhere else?

Answer (score 6):

The short answer: No, there is no current interface exposed to allow a measure block more than ten times.

The longer answer: No, but there is an interface exposed to modify certain metrics of the measure block.  The default metrics are in a String array returned from `defaultPerformanceMetrics`.  There appears to only be one metric supported right now: [`XCTPerformanceMetric_WallClockTime`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctperformancemetric_wallclocktime).  This only specifies a performance metric that records the time in seconds between calls to a performance test's `startMeasuring()` and `stopMeasuring()` methods, and not the number of times the block is run.

Comment: can we not decrease it as well ?

Answer (score 1):

I typically expand the Standard Deviation value to include the range I'd accept.

One obvious workaround for you is to perform the operation 5 times within the measure block you are executing. (You'll want to change the expected time.)

```
    measure {
        for _ in [1...5] {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: This only iterates once, since `[1...5]` is just an array containing a single element.